# In a piston pushing water down a tube, is the motion of the particles in the form of a wave?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves

What I was wondering is this. If I had a tube with water in it, with one end open and the other with a piston-like device attached to it, I can imagine that if I was to give the water a pulse, this would transmit down the tube as a mechanical wave as particles collide with each other - something like sound.

But if we picture a scenario where instead of a pulse, I begin moving the piston down the tube at a constant velocity, what would the motion of the particles look like? Also what would this look like with air?

Comment: Well, if you stop moving the piston the disturbance propagates forward. It is a wave, but a pretty complex non-sinusoidal single-frequency wave.

Answer (score 0):

For slow piston speeds, the motion of the water molecules is called *bulk flow* and the speed with which you move the piston will equal the speed with which the water exits the other end of the pipe.

IN bulk flow, all the molecules move in concert with the piston movement which is superimposed on their jiggling thermal motion.

The molecules right next the the tube walls are more or less "stuck" to the walls and move very slowly if at all, whereas the molecules at the center of the pipe move with the full velocity of the piston. This *velocity profile* gets established within a short distance along the pipe length, typically several pipe diameters.

For slow piston speeds, the water molecules slide past each other smoothly throughout the velocity profile and a parcel of water at the center of the pipe doesn't get mixed with water next to the wall. This is called *laminar flow*.

Faster flow causes a transition to a new flow regime called *turbulent flow* in which the water parcels across the pipe cross-section get vigorously mixed and swirled all together as they travel down the pipe.

Now, if instead of smoothly pushing on the piston you give it a good hard smack with a hammer, then the bulk movement becomes quite small and a *sound wave* travels away from the piston at the speed of sound in the water.

Comment: Say I slowly press the piston. Almost instantly as I start pressing, water starts flowing out the other end. This "information" reaches the other end I think at the speed of mechanical waves in the medium, since it's from particles being pushed from the ones before it. So what I want to know is, maybe if we look at the slow uniform motion of a slowly moving piston in short time intervals, can this motion be thought of as wave pulses transmitting down the tube

Answer (score 0):

The answer of what the flow looks like depends on the characteristics of the fluid and the tube itself (fluid viscosity/Reynolds number (Re), tube length, diameter, shape, roughness, etc).

Assuming a long, cylindrical tube we can visualize the shape of the fluid velocity profile as a function of the radius of the tube:

The fluid at the plunger (due to boundary conditions) will have a "plug flow" distribution--all fluid moving the same speed as the plunger, independent of radius.

As this plug flow proceeds down the pipe, there are primarily two different outcomes:
1 - If the flow velocity is fast (large Re), the velocity profile will remain plug flow to the other outlet of the pipe [turbulent flow]
2 - If the flow velocity is slow (low Re), the velocity profile will trend towards parabolic with respect to radius [laminar flow].

Air is compressible and would tend more towards the plug flow velocity profile as the pressure wave travels through the tube.

[image: Parabolic (laminar) Flow vs Plug (turbulent) Flow]